# Identifying mystery hops

Tags: hops, growing-hops

I've just discovered a reasonable crop of hops climbing a fir tree in my back garden!  Any advice on how to identify the variety?  I'm in London UK.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Even if you can't identify the strain, you can try using the cones to brew test batches, to see if it's any good as bittering hops, aroma or flavor. I did this with a batch of random "ornamental" hops, and liked the results enough to try to cultivate them.

Comment: Nice idea I may give that a try

Answer (score 5):

I've spoken with hop growers and wholesalers about this before, and short of a DNA analysis there is almost no way to know for certain.  You can make a rough guess based on the appearance of the hops and history of the area, but that's about it.